# std::map<my_enum, base_class> insert error: base_class is an inaccessibile base of derived_class

Tags: c++11

This little program has to write an xml file.
Building the code I get the following error:
`K:\Sergio\cpp\xml\sergio\cbp6s\main.cpp|32|error: 'base_tag' is an inaccessible base of 'tag'` 
In short, I have two classes derived from base_tag (xml_declaration and tag) and I want insert (or emplace) in a std::map some std::pair elements. 
Building, the first insert works (`std::pair<order::declaration, xml_declaration>`), but the second fails (`std::pair<order::root, tag_object>`). 
Between the object are derived from `base_tag` 
Where am I wrong?

**File tag.hpp** :

```
#ifndef _TAG_HPP_
#define _TAG_HPP_

#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>

enum class tag_type
{
    closing = -1,
    autoclosed = 0,
    opening  = 1
};

using attribute = std::pair<std::string, std::string>;

class base_tag
{
public:
    base_tag();
    virtual ~base_tag();

    virtual std::string get();
    bool attribute_exists(std::string);
    std::string get_attribute_value(std::string name);
    bool add_attribute(std::string name, std::string value);

protected:

    std::vector<std::pair<std::string, std::string>> _attributes;
};

// ------------------------------------------------------------ 

class xml_declaration : public base_tag
{
public:
    xml_declaration();
    ~xml_declaration();
    std::string get();
};

// ----------------------------------------------------------

class tag : base_tag
{
public:
    tag(std::string name);
    tag(std::string name, tag_type tt );
    std::string get();
    void set_ident(size_t ident);

protected:
    std::string _name;
    tag_type _tt;
};

#endif // _TAG_HPP_
```

**File tag.cpp**

```
#include "tag.hpp"

base_tag::base_tag()
{
}

base_tag::~base_tag()
{
    _attributes.clear();
}

bool base_tag::attribute_exists(std::string name)
{
    bool res = false;

    for(auto & i : _attributes)
    {
        if (i.first == name)
            res = true;
    }

    return res;
}

bool base_tag::add_attribute(std::string name, std::string value)
{
    bool res = false;

    if(!attribute_exists(name))
    {
        attribute a = std::make_pair(name, value);
        _attributes.push_back(a);
        res = true;
    }
    return res;
}

std::string base_tag::get()
{
    return u8"<invalid_tag/>";
}

// -------------------------------------------------------

xml_declaration::xml_declaration(): base_tag()
{
    add_attribute("version", "1.0");
    add_attribute("encoding", "UTF-8");
    add_attribute("standalone", "yes");
}

xml_declaration::~xml_declaration()
{ }

std::string xml_declaration::get()
{
    std::string res = u8"<?xml";
    for(auto & i : _attributes)
    {
        res.push_back(' ');
        res += i.first;
        res += u8"=\"";
        res += i.second;
        res += u8"\"";
    }
    res += u8" ?>";
    return res;
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------

tag::tag(std::string name):base_tag(), _name(name)
{
    _tt = tag_type::autoclosed;
}

tag::tag(std::string name, tag_type tt ): base_tag(), _name(name), 
_tt(tt)
{ }

std::string tag::get()
{
    std::string res = u8"";

    bool with_attributes = !(_attributes.empty());
    switch(_tt)
    {
        case tag_type::autoclosed : {    
            res = u8"<";
            res += _name;
            if(with_attributes)
            {
                for(auto & i : _attributes)
                {
                    res.push_back(' ');
                    res += i.first;
                    res += u8"=\"";
                    res += i.second;
                    res += u8"\"";
                }
            };
                    res += u8"/>";
                    break;
        }

    case tag_type::opening :   {   
                    res = u8"<";
                    res += _name;
                    for(auto & i : _attributes)
                    {
                        res.push_back(' ');
                        res += i.first;
                        res += u8"=\"";
                        res += i.second;
                        res += u8"\"";
                    }
                        res += u8">";
                        break;
                            }

    case tag_type::closing :  {   
                        res = u8"</";
                        res += _name;
                        res.push_back('>');
                        }

    default :           break;

    }
    return res;
}
```

**File main.cpp**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <utility>
#include "tag.hpp"

using namespace std;

enum class order
{
    declaration     = 0,
    root            = 1,
    file_version    = 4,
    project         = 10,
    project_closing = 998,
    root_closing    = 1000
};

int main()
{
    std::map<order, base_tag> tree;

    xml_declaration decl;
    cout << decl.get() << endl;

    tag t1("project_file", tag_type::opening);
    tag t2("project_file", tag_type::closing);

    tree.insert(std::pair<order, base_tag>(order::declaration, 
decl));
    tree.insert(std::pair<order, base_tag>(order::root, t1));
    tree.insert(std::pair<order, base_tag>(order::root, t2));
//  tree.emplace(std::pair<order, base_tag>(order::root_closing, t1));

    cout << tree.size() << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

I'm using Code::Blocks with GCC 5.1.0 (on Windows 10).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the error message says, `tag` inherits `base_tag` privately. If you change its headline into

```
class tag: public base_tag;
```

(same as your `xml_declaration` which inherits `base_tag` publicly) then it will officially be-a base tag.

A more serious problem is that you try to store instances of inherited classes in a container of a base class by value. What happens then is, objects get sliced and lose their whole derived functionality; you put an object of a derived class into a map, but you actually store an object of a based class in it (that's the reason some people tend to say polymorphic base classes should necessarily be abstract.) Use (smart) pointers or `reference_wrapper`s as `map`'s mapped type.